# ExecutorService Future::get very slow

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, future, executorservice

I'm parallelizing a quite complex program to get it faster. For this I use most of the time the `ExecutorService`. Until now it worked pretty well, but then I noticed that just one line of code makes my program run half as fast as it could. It's the line with `exactScore.get()`.

I don't know why, but it sometimes needs more that 0.1 s just to get the double value of the Future Object.

Why is this? How can I handle it that it runs faster?  Is there a way to write directly in the `Double[]` while multithreading?
Thanks

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);

    // initialize output
    Double[] presortedExScores = new Double[sortedHeuScores.length];

    for(int i =0; i < sortedHeuScores.length; i++ ){
        final int index = i;
        final Collection<MolecularFormula> formulas_for_exact_method = multimap.get(sortedHeuScores[i]);
        for (final MolecularFormula formula : formulas_for_exact_method){
            Future<Double> exactScore = service.submit(new Callable<Double>() {
                @Override
                public Double call() throws Exception {
                    return getScore(computeTreeExactly(computeGraph(formula)));
                }
            });
            presortedExScores[index] = exactScore.get();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is to be expected. It isn't "slower" then; it is just doing its job.

From the javadoc for [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()):

*Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.*

Long story short: it seems that you do not understand the concepts you are using in your code. The idea of a **Future** is that it does things at some point *in the future*.

And by calling `get()` you express: I don't mind waiting *now* until the results of that computation "behind" that Future become available.

Thus: you have to step back and look into your code again; to understand how your different "threads of activity" really work; and how/when they come back together.

One idea that comes to mind: right now, you you are creating your Future objects in a loop; and directly after you created the Future, you call `get()` on it. That completely contradicts the idea of creating multiple Futures. In other words: instead of going:

```
foreach X
  create future X.i
  wait/get future X.i
```

you could do something like

```
foreach X
  create future X.i

foreach X
  wait/get for future X.i
```

In other words: allow your futures to really do things in parallel; instead of enforcing **sequential** processing.

If that doesn't help "enough", then as said: you have to look at your overall design, and determine if there are ways to further "pull apart" things. Right now all activity happens "closely" together; and surprise: when you do a lot of work at the same time, that takes time. But as you might guess: such a re-design could be a lot of work; and is close to impossible without knowing more about your problem/code base.

A more sophisticated approach would be that you write code where some each Future has a way of expressing "I am done" - then you would "only" start all Futures; and wait until the last one comes back. But as said; I can't design a full solution for you here.

The other really important take-away here: don't just blindly use some code that "happens" to work. One essence of programming is to understand **each and any** concept used in your source code. You should have a pretty good idea what your code is doing **before** running it and finding "oh, that `get()` makes things slow".

Comment: so would it be better if I don't try to get it already in the for loop? Because if I understand you correctly the other Executors will not get jobs until my exactScor.get is completed (so no new multithreads in this time).

Comment: Please see my various updates. It could help to split things in two loops; but that really depends on things that go beyond a simple SO question/answer discussion.